# How can I animate this Raphael SVG Diagram Skillbar?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, svg, raphael

I want to use Raphael Diagram Skillbar that is in the following link:

**[HERE](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/04/22/animated-skills-diagram/)**

But I want to show each line with animation like this: (animation at start position)

**[HERE](http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html)**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you can achieve without Raphael:
http://jsfiddle.net/1q70b8Ld/

To draw arcs, you can use `<path>` like this:

```
<path stroke="orange" d="M0,-40 A40,40 0,0,1 40,0"/>
```

And to get the correct `d` syntax for any starting and ending angle, you can add a piece of Javascript:

```
function path(radius, start, end) {
    while (end < start) end += 360;
    var x1 = Math.sin(Math.PI * start / 180) * radius;   
    var y1 = - Math.cos(Math.PI * start / 180) * radius;   
    var x2 = Math.sin(Math.PI * end / 180) * radius;   
    var y2 = - Math.cos(Math.PI * end / 180) * radius;

    return "M" + x1 + "," + y1
        + "A" + radius + "," + radius + " "
        + "0," + (end - start > 180 ? 1 : 0) + ",1 "
        + x2 + "," + y2;
}
```